# What's wrong with putting an ivar in a class extension?

Tags: objective-c, interface, instance-variables, class-extensions

According to Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html), this should work in my code:

```
@interface Menu () {
    int testIvar;

}
 -(void)privateMethod;

@end
```

This works if I don't try to declare an iVar. As soon as I add the curly braces and what is between them, I get this nice red warning:

> Expected identifier or '(' before '{' token

What's going on here?

Comment: That looks fine. Does your runtime support class extensions? What's your target platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Turning my comment into an answer...)

GCC of any kind won't do this for you, nor will LLVM < 2.0, as the docs you linked to state:

> Using the Clang/LLVM 2.0 compiler, you can also declare properties and instance variables in a class extension.

Make sure you're using the most recent compiler available to you (if you're using Xcode < 4 you may be out of luck).

Comment: thanks, i'm using Xcode 4.2. I guess it doesn't support this out-of-the box?

Comment: I thought the default compiler for 4.2 was LLVM 2.1... You can check -- in the sidebar, click on your project, look at the "Build Settings" tab, "Build Options" section, "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C". There should be at least one option that doesn't mention GCC at all (maybe "Apple LLVM 2.1"?). That's the one you want.

Comment: it says LLVM GCC 4.2. There is one other compiler, Apple LLVM 3.0. Interesting, this is a new project, and in this menu it says the Apple LLVM 3.0 is the default, but clearly, the default was actually GCC 4.2, as I've never changed this. The reason I want to do all this is to define private instance variables that are not mentioned in the header. I suppose I could go the @property route instead unless I plan to switch compilers. Any other nasties I should expect if I switch compiler mid project?

Comment: Yup, you want the Apple LLVM 3.0. So far as I know, LLVM without the GCC frontend only works _better_ -- they've maintained compatibility and added stuff (like ivars in class extensions). I don't think you'll have a problem, but please don't make me swear that in court.

Comment: Also, interesting aside: you can [declare ivars right in the `@implementation`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122413/whats-the-difference-between-adding-pseudo-private-ivars-in-a-class-extension-o)(there are other SO questions about it) -- no need for an extension!

Comment: very cool. i've heard about this but never seen it in sample code or books

Comment: the technique in that article must also be compiler specific. I get errors of various types when I try to do this.

Comment: Yes, it's another LLVM > 2.0 only feature. Quite handy, though.